# How can I verify the ratio of Lucas numbers to fibonacci numbers algebreically

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

The article:

"The Lucas numbers 1,3,4...are the sums of alternate Fibonacci numbers. The ratios of Lucas to Fibonacci must satisfy: $R_j = \frac{F_{i+1}+F_{i-1}}{F_i}=\frac{2F_{i+1}}{F_i-1}$

I know that Fibonacci numbers and Lucas are the same except their starting values.

Can someone show how the ratio between the two equal the given condition that was set for $R_j$

Comment: You just need to show (perhaps by induction) that $L_j = F_{j-1} + F_{j+1}$. Then the first ratio follows. For the second, I think you mean $\dfrac {2F_{i+1}} {F_i}-1$ instead, and that follows easily from the first ratio and definition of Fibonacci numbers.